# Vue url with two different IDs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuex

I am trying to delete a user from the team but I am not sure how to pass team ID and the deleting user ID in the same URL. I tried to pass two param but I am unable to `deleteUserFromTeam` in VUE file.

actions:

```js
  deleteUserFromTeam(context,data){
      return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        axiosService({ requiresAuth: true })
        .delete(`/administration/teams/${data.team_id}/members/${data.user_id}`)
          .then(() => resolve(context.commit(types.DELETE_USER_FROM_TEAM, data.id)))
          .catch((error) => reject(error));
      })
    },
```

mutations:

```js
[types.DELETE_USER_FROM_TEAM](state, payload) {
      const idx = state.teamsList.findIndex((user) => user.id === payload);
      state.teamsList.splice(idx, 1);
    },
```

TeamUser.vue

```
  <div class="card mt-3">
    <div class="card-header">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs mb-1">
        <button @click="usersPage()" class="btn btn-primary mt-1 ms-2">
          <i class="bi bi-plus"> Add Users </i>
        </button>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="col">
        <table class="table table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Users</th>
              <th>Email</th>
              <th>
                {{ $t("edit").capitalize() }} <i class="hi hi-pencil-square" />
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr v-for="user of currentTeam.users" :key="user.id" :id="user.id">
              <td>{{ user.userName }}</td>
              <td>{{ user.userEmail }}</td>
              <td>
                <button
                  class="btn btn-close"
                  @click="$refs.deleteUserDialog.show()"
                >
                 
                </button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <base-rich-list-item />

         <bs-dialog ref="deleteUserDialog" :header="$t('deleteUser').capitalize()">
        <template v-slot:body>
          <div
            class="alert alert-danger"
            role="alert"
            v-if="errorMessageDeleteDialog !== null"
          >
            {{ errorMessageDeleteDialog }}
          </div>
          <p>{{ $t("delete").capitalize() }} '{{ user }}'?</p>
        </template>
        <template v-slot:footer>
          <button
            class="btn btn-secondary"
            @click.stop="$refs.deleteUserDialog.close()"
          >
            {{ $t("cancel").capitalize() }}
          </button>
          <button
            class="btn btn-danger"
            @click.stop="
              deleteUserMember();
              $refs.deleteUserDialog.close();
            "
          >
            <span v-if="isLoading" class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" />
            {{ $t("delete").capitalize() }}
          </button>
        </template>
      </bs-dialog>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapActions, mapState } from "vuex";
import BaseRichListItem from "@/components/ui/BaseRichListItem";
import BsDialog from "@/components/ui/BsDialog";

export default {
  name: "AddUsersToTeams",
  components: [BaseRichListItem,BsDialog],
  data() {
    return {
      addUser: false,
      editUsers: false,
      date: false,
      isLoading: false,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState("administration/teams", ["currentTeam"]),
    ...mapState("administration/users", ["userList"]),
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions("administration/teams", ["deleteUserFromTeam"]),
    usersPage() {
      this.$router.push({ name: "AddUsersDialog" });
    },
    deleteUserMember(){
      console.log('delete user');

      this.isLoading = true;
      this.deleteUserFromTeam({ team_id: this.currentTeam.id, user_id:this.user.id})
        .then(() => {
          this.$router.push(`/administration/teams/${this.currentTeam.id}`);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          this.errorMessageDeleteDialog = error;
        })
        .finally(() => {
          this.isLoading = false;
        });
    },
    
    submitUpdatedUsers() {},
  },
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Comment: This lacks all the code. If you pass in the correct id it should just work.

Comment: `          this.$router.push("/administration/teams/:teamId");
` This line doesn't make sense. Did you mean to pass `teamId` to this? If so, you have to actually pass it. Right now its just a string

Comment: Thanks for the response. I added my complete vue code. I am still having the issue 'undefined id'

Answer (score 0):

Replace the following line

```js
 this.$router.push("/administration/teams/:teamId");
```

with this

```js
 this.$router.push(`/administration/teams/${this.currentTeam.id}`);
```

Comment: Thank you for the correction, but the problem is with the user_id and I am unable to resolve the problem.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Perhaps you at least know the line in the source code where the error is?